# how can i run a customize logger from a function in python

Tags: python, function, logging

I have created a customize logger function in Python file test.py:

```py
import logging
def logger1():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('employee.log')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

And created another test1.py file where I doing below operation and trying to log data

```py
from utility.test import logger1
class Employee:
    """A sample Employee class"""
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        logger1.logger.info('Created Employee: {} - {}'.format(self.fullname, self.email))
    @property
    def email(self):
        return '{}.{}@email.com'.format(self.first, self.last)
    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)
```

But when I run this Python file test1.py, I get the following error:

> ```sh
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/python/SeleniumFramework/utility/test2.py", line 21, in <module>
>     emp_1 = Employee('John', 'Smith')
> File "C:/python/SeleniumFramework/utility/test2.py", line 10, in __init__
>     logger1.logger.info('Created Employee: {} - {}'.format(self.fullname, self.email))
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'logger'
> ```

Note: Without creating a function of customize logger it is working file.

Comment: Variables inside a function exist only while the function is running, you can not access them at any later time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the brackets behind logger1...

This means to get logger1 you will need to call it and not pass the functions reference:

```
logger1().info("Look I am log")
```

Btw with this function you will always create a new logging instance which is not your intention I think.